# Create a Custom Login page for logged in Users with Mvc5 Identity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am trying to find a guide or something that can teach me to make a view that users navigate to when they login. The view should show profile properties like firstname,lastname, and additional custom data. The problem is I dont know how to send the id from login to a another view. In other words when this succeeds in AccountController...

```
      case SignInStatus.Success:
      return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
   // return RedirectToAction("Customer", "Account");
```

... I want to send id to another view. I tried make a view like so:

```
      public ActionResult Customer(string userId)
       {
        ApplicationDbContext _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(_context));
        var ThisUser = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        //string a = Convert.ToString(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        //RegisterViewModel RVM = db.RegisterViewModels.Find(a);

        return View(ThisUser);
    }
```

It did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: The standard MVC template already includes some logic for this. Did you check the ManageController?

Comment: Thank you I had no Idea it did, and  I did not find any tutorial which mentioned it either cheers mate!

Comment: Added an answer with a link that will give you plenty of information about ASP.NET Identity. If that answer is good to you, you can accept it so this can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of information to found about ASP.NET Identity on the web, in particular Microsoft's own documentation is really good. Check [this](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/samples/aspnet-identity) out for a starter for some great examples.